# Проверка ключа через preg_match

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

С регулярками практически не дружу, но надо проверять переменную, чтобы пропускалась строка такого формата HY7Q8S-Y9QO0W-QMD7F1-PQ2Z9X

Каждая часть 6 символов, всего 27 символов, между каждой частью стоит -

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться выражением вида

```
<?php
$str = 'HY7Q8S-Y9QO0W-QMD7F1-PQ2Z9X';
$pattern = '/^[0-9A-Z]{6}-[0-9A-Z]{6}-[0-9A-Z]{6}-[0-9A-Z]{6}$/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $str)) echo 'соответствует';
else echo 'не соответствует';
```

Comment: А что-то вроде [0-9a-z][-]{27} Это все не то?

Comment: @DimaRRR Это не совсем то, у вас получилось один любой символ 0-9a-z и 27 тире. Можно так [-0-9a-z]{27}, но в этом случае тире можно будет добавлять в произвольное место, включая начало и конец строки.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!)

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = '/^(?:[0-9A-Z]{6}(?:-|$)){4}/';
```

4 раза по 6 символов справа от которых `-` или конец текста.